In Service 401(k) Rollover
The IRS seems to allow one 401(K) rollover to IRA per 12 month period BUT does anyone reading this have a good feel for what percentage of 401(k) plan administrators allow "In Service" 401(k) rollovers. My client base is spread among many different 401(k) plans.

The one-per-year rule applies to IRA-to-IRA rollovers but not 401k plans. Specifically, it applies to 60-day indirect IRA-to-IRA rollovers and not to direct trustee-to-trustee transfers. There may be research out there that estimates the percentage of plans that allow in-service distributions, but I'm not sure how that relates to personal finance.

"My client base is spread among many different 401(k) plans." so what does your sample data suggest?
